# cannot read property of type "length" of undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript

the idea is, when you refresh the page, it picks random colours, and they all get assigned in the 6x6 grid, but I receive an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at pickColor (colorgame.js:30)
    at colorgame.js:3
```

I'm really new to javascript (1 week actually and I'm not really sure) I have gone around the internet in search of the answer but I can't make sense of it all

```js
var colors = generateRandomColors(6);
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = pickColor(colors);
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
var messageDisplay = document.querySelector("#message");

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i]
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
        if (clickedColor === pickedColor){
            messageDisplay.textContent = "Correct!";
            changeColors(clickedColor)
        } else{
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#232323"
            messageDisplay.textContent = "Try Again!"
        }
    })
}

function changeColors(){
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = pickedColor;
    }
}

function pickColor(colors){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    return colors[random];
}

function generateRandomColors(num){
    var arr = []
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        arr.push(randomColor())
    }
}

function randomColor(){
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}
```

```html
  <h1 id="title">The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> Game</h1>

    <div>
        <span id="message"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div id="container">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Go to the line throwing the error. Find out why the code is doing the equivalent of “undefined.length”. Walk back through the code up until that point as necessary.

Comment: `generateRandomColors` returns nothing, it's undefined :) So, let it just do `return arr`

Comment: Hint: generateRandomColors does not return what is assumed.

Comment: thank you! it is working now!

Comment: I understand you're new to javascript, but please avoid questions seeking for debug help. I'd suggest you take some courses and learn how to debug your code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `generateRandomColors` should return `arr`.
Otherwise its return value will be `undefined` and hence, does not have a property `length`.